# SonataAdminBundle: как вывести в choice результаты из другого entity?

Tags: symfony, php, doctrine, symfony2

Ситуация такова:
У меня в базе много `OneToMany`, а `Sonata` дает делать только одно наследие. Что бы сделать свой `Form Type` для следующих наследий не хватит опыта, да и время. По этому решил сделать `Choice` и таким образом связывать таблицы.

нашел похожее решение решение: [Пример выподающего списка в форме редактирования](http://ruslanix.com/it-blog/sonataadmin-choice-list-in-form-filters/#more-761), но не понимаю как достать `EntityManager`, выдает все время

> Error: Call to undefined method Application\Sonata\AdminBundle\Admin\ProductCategoryAdmin::getEntityManager() in ...

Мой код:

```
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;

//

protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
{
    $em = $this->getEntityManager();
    $formMapper
                ->add(
                    'page',
                    'choice',
                    array(
                        'choices' => function() use ($em){
                                $pages = $em->getRepository('LdbCoreBundle:Page')
                                            ->findAll();
                                $choices = array();
                                foreach($pages as $page)
                                    $choices[$page->getId()] = $page->getPageurl();

                                return $choices;
                                }

                    )
                )
```

Answer (score 3):

`entity` тип вполне подходит. В качестве `property` можно указать "`pageurl`"

[entity Field Type](http://symfony.com/doc/master/reference/forms/types/entity.html)

> A special choice field that's designed to load options from a Doctrine entity. For example, if you have a Category entity, you could use this field to display a select field of all, or some, of the Category objects from the database.

Answer (score 1):

Поддержу [@digi](/users/8713/digi), тип entity решает проблему. Вот как я делал у себя на проекте:

```
$builder
        ->add('company','entity',
            array(
                'class'         => 'MainSiteBundle:Company',
                'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $repository) { return $repository->createQueryBuilder('c')->orderBy('c.id', 'ASC'); },
                'property'      => 'name',
                'label'         => 'Company',
                'empty_value'   => 'Choose a company',
            )
        );
```